# Equivalent condition for continuity on a metric (or normed) space.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a metric (or normed) space and let $f : X → X$. Show that $f$ is continuous at $x \in X$ if and only if, whenever $x_n \to x$ in X, some subsequence of $(f(x_n))$ converges to $f(x).$

The forward direction can be done easily. I am having trouble for the backward direction. I am thinking to approach it using contradiction, assuming that $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(x)$ and hence getting some trouble with the continuity.

Comment: Yes, by contradiction is very good.

Comment: But I am unable to execute it, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

suppose $f$ is not continuous at $x$, i.e. there is $\varepsilon >0$ s.t. for all $\delta >0$, there $y\in X$ s.t. $\|y-x\|<\delta $ and $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\geq \varepsilon $. In particular, for all $n\in\mathbb N$ there is $x_n\in X$ s.t. $\|x-x_n\|<\frac{1}{n}$ and $\|f(x_n)-f(x)\|\geq \varepsilon $.

In particular, $x_n\to x$ but $f(x_n)\not\to f(x)$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: The contradiction is not valid, since we are taking some subsequence of f(xn) to be converging to x whenever xn converges to x. But, in the answer, use of convergence of f(xn) (which is not given) has been used to get to the contradiction. @Surb

Comment: @DaminiDhiman: I didn't pay attention to the fact that $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ for some subsequence (I thought that it has to hold for all sequence). But obviously, there are no subseqeunce of $f(x_n)$ that will converges to $f(x)$. So the contradiction is almost valid... (just justify when there are no subsequence s.t. $f(x_{n_k})\to f(x)$, but the argument is straightforward).

Comment: I don't really get it, why is it obvious that there are no subsequence of f(xn) that will converge to f(x), when we are already given with the existence of such subsequence. Are you concluding the non-existence of such subsequence from the last statement that f(xn) does not converge to f(x) (which(such conclusion) is not true either). @Surb

Comment: Suppose there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ s.t. $f(x_{n_k})$ converges to $f(x)$. In particular, there is $K>0$ s.t. $|f(x_{n_k})-f(x)|\leq \frac{\varepsilon }{2}<\varepsilon $ for all $k\geq K$, which contradict the fact that $|f(x_{n})-f(x)|\geq \varepsilon $ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. @DaminiDhiman

Comment: Oh, alright! Thank you so much @Surb